# PyZMQ one-way communication

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

I took a look at the various ZMQ messaging patterns and I'm not sure which one would do for my project. All I want to do is be able to connect to a server and send a command (the client never receive anything). On the server side, I want to be able to check if there is a message, if there is one, process it, else continue to do other stuff **without blocking**. That way, the server could continue to work even if there is no client connected.

```
#client.py
while(True):
    select = raw_input()
    if select == "1":
       socket.send(msg1)
    elif select == "2":
       socket.send(msg2)
    ...

#server.py
while(True):
    msg = socket.recv() #should not block
    if msg == ...
        #do stuff
    #do other stuff
```

So which pattern should I use with ZMQ to do that? Example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, since you want one-way communication with only one socket receiving messages, that generally means PUSH-PULL. Here is a version of the client:

```
import zmq

ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
s = ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)
url = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'
s.connect(url)

while True:
    msg = raw_input("msg > ")
    s.send(msg)
    if msg == 'quit':
        break
```

so a PUSH socket sends the messages we get from raw_input. It should be clear how to change that logic to generate the messages you want. A bit of bonus is that if you type 'quit', both the client and the server will quit.

There are a variety of ways to do the non-blocking server, depending on the complexity of your application. I'll show a few examples, from the most basic one to the most powerful / extensible.

All of these server examples assume this at the top, setting up the server's PULL socket:

```
import time
import zmq

ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
s = ctx.socket(zmq.PULL)
url = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'
s.bind(url)
```

The first example is simple non-blocking recv, which raises a `zmq.Again` Exception if there are no messages ready to be received:

```
# server0.py

while True:
    try:
        msg = s.recv(zmq.NOBLOCK) # note NOBLOCK here
    except zmq.Again:
        # no message to recv, do other things
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("received %r" % msg)
        if msg == 'quit':
            break
```

But that pattern is pretty hard to extend beyond very simple cases. The second example uses a Poller, to check for events on the socket:

```
# server1.py

poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(s)

while True:
    events = dict(poller.poll(0))
    if s in events:
        msg = s.recv()
        print("received %r" % msg)
        if msg == 'quit':
            break
    else:
        # no message to recv, do other things
        time.sleep(1)
```

In this toy example, this is very similar to the first. But, unlike the first, it is easy to extend to many sockets or events with further calls to `poller.register`, or passing a timeout other than zero to `poller.poll`.

The last example uses an eventloop, and actually registers a callback for when messages arrive. You can build very complex applications with this sort of pattern, and it is a fairly straightforward way to write code that only does work when there is work to be done.

```
# server2.py

from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
from zmq.eventloop.zmqstream import ZMQStream

def print_msg(msg):
    print("received %r" % ' '.join(msg))
    if msg[0] == 'quit':
        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

# register the print_msg callback to be fired
# whenever there is a message on our socket
stream = ZMQStream(s)
stream.on_recv(print_msg)

# do other things in the meantime
tic = time.time()
def do_other_things():
    print("%.3f" % (time.time() - tic))

pc = ioloop.PeriodicCallback(do_other_things, 1000)
pc.start()

# start the eventloop
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

So that's a few basic ways to deal with zmq messages without blocking. You can grab these examples [together as a gist](https://gist.github.com/minrk/9150423).